# should i use Except or Contains when dealing with HashSet or so in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

Look at this:

```
 var query = myDic.Select(x => x.Key).Except(myHashSet);
```

or

```
 var query = myDic.Select(x => x.Key).where(y=>!myHashSet.Contains(y))
```

i guess a O(1) version of `Contains` will be invoked due to polymophism in first case.
Don't know about `except` though.

**Update**

Exept is also O(1) in my case.

[why linq's `except` extension method does not have Except<TSource> Method (IEnumerable<TSource>,HashSet<TSource>) overload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7214616/why-linqs-except-extension-method-does-not-have-excepttsource-method-ienume)

Answer (score 1):

If your `myDic` is a normal .NET Dictionary then I will go with

```
myDic.Keys.Except(myHashSet)
```

for readability.

To speak of your options, the first one is O(n+m) whereas the second O(n), neither of which tells you which finishes first for your collection size. When in doubt race both the horses.

@sehe's answer is O(n+m) too but most probably it will be faster than your O(n+m) solution.

Answer (score 0):

> var query = myDic.Select(x => x.Key).Except(myHashSet);

The Except will be the extension on IEnumerable (the result of Select). This is *not* O(1)

> myHashSet.Contains(y)
>   Is indeed calling the member function, which is O(n)

---

Consider

```
new HashSet<K>(myDic.Select(x => x.Key)).ExceptWith(myHashSet);
```

Also look at HashSet<>.SymmetricExceptWith()

Comment: Actually, `Enumerable.Except()` *is* O(n) (or rather O(n + m)), it uses a hash set internally. Your version with creating new `HashSet` has the same time complexity.

Comment: @svick: excuse the sloppy typo. That ought to have said O(1) there...; Also of course creating a temp HashSet<> in the same line is not going to gain much, but it can be cached, if the keyset doesn't change much.

Comment: @svick: if `Except` uses hash set internally, why it is not O(1)? provided the argument passed into is `HashSet` already

Comment: @colinfang, because it has to iterate at least over one of the two collections.

Comment: @svick: aha, I mean in each query iteration it is O(1), and u mentioned the entire stream. Misunderstood u. But, I still worried that as in `Except()` it uses the construstor: `new Hashset(ICollection)`, I am afraid the size of `myHashSet` still matters, though no longer multiplied by the query iterations. That's why u said O(n+m) isn't it?