# why linq's `except` extension method does not have Except<TSource> Method (IEnumerable<TSource>,HashSet<TSource>) overload?

Tags: c#, linq

why linq's `except` extension method does not have `Except<TSource>` Method `(IEnumerable<TSource>,HashSet<TSource>)` overload?

for example

```
  var query = A.Except(B).where(x=>Criteria(x))

  foreach(item in query)
   {
     B.add(item);
     DoSomething(item);
   }
```

Given B is `HashSet<T>`, A is `IEnumerable<T>` or `ICollection<T>`
Here in each iteration `Except` take O(|B|) time.
why there is not a method that just take O(1) time, as B is Hashset anyway.

**Update**

my crude way is

```
var query = A.where(x=>!B.contains(x)).where(x=>Criteria(x))
```

Comment: I don't really know what you're asking...

Comment: I encourage you to answer your own question by attempting to write an O(1) implementation of Except as you describe.

Comment: And now you know why there is no such method: because writing your own takes a user only 23 keystrokes.  Is the expense of designing, implementing, testing, documenting and maintaining the method you describe really worth the savings of about ten keystrokes for a small number of users?

Comment: I really wish we could ban these "why does the framework not have X method?" questions. They're pointless.

Comment: @Tridus: There was recently a question asking "why does the framework have all these methods?" I thought that was especially lame.

Comment: @Tridus Not always, sometimes the insight gained is really interesting, for example Eric Lipperts answer/blog posting about why there is no ForEach led to some great insight about side effects and the purpose of LINQ methods, Mutability etc. Unless they are worded in the "Why is Microsoft so stupid and can't get stuff right" way, which this question doesn't seem to be.

Comment: @michael-stum But they're also not really answerable. Nobody knows *why* the framework doesn't have method X unless they work at Microsoft (and even then they likely don't). At best, people are guessing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Here in each iteration Except take O(|B|) time

No it doesn't. `Except` is implemented internally with a collection similar to `HashSet<T>`. You can have a look at [Jon Skeet's proposed implementation in Edulinq](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/12/30/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-17-except/). All elements in `B` are placed in a `HashSet<T>`, then elements of A are enumerated; if they're not in the `HashSet` (checking this is a O(1) operation), they are returned in the output sequence.

Comment: thank you,pal. all the comments attached to my question were of no help if not ignorant. And ur answer is EXACTLY what I want.

Comment: wait, does that mean B.add() afterwards won't effect the query any more? As `Except()` reads the entire B at first run, once for all.

Comment: If you add something to B after you start enumerating the query, no, it won't affect the results. But if you restart the enumeration, it will.

Comment: cheers, exactly as I expected.