# C# fast Except method for sorted list

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq, list

I am working on an application whose bottleneck is list1.Except(list2). From this post : [should i use Except or Contains when dealing with HashSet or so in Linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7211349/should-i-use-except-or-contains-when-dealing-with-hashset-or-so-in-linq) the complexity of except is O(m+n) (m and n standing for the sizes of the lists). However, my lists are sorted. Can this help ?

The first implementation I can think of :

```
foreach element in list2 (m operations)
    look for it in list1 (ln(n) operations)
    if present 
        set it to null (O(1), removing has a O(n))
    else continue
```

It has complexity O(m*ln(n)), which is very interesting when m is small and n is large (this is exactly the case with my data sets : m is around 50, n is around 1 000 000). However the fact that it produces null may have a lot of implications on the functions using it... Is there any way to keep this complexity, without having to write nulls (and then keeping track of them)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Create your own extension method that uses [BinarySearch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4e7fxsh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: The first thing is that as you've noticed the behaviour of these two things is different. Also if your algorithm is complexity m*ln(n) then for big m and small n then at a glance it looks like it is going to be much the same performance so the complexity might not help and you might need to just benchmark things and see which performs better.

Comment: Actually, I forgot to mention that m was around 50 and n is around 1 000 000

Comment: @Damien I think I am not getting your suggestion right. As I understand it, stepping through the two lists sequentially should be O(m+n)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var listM = new List<int>();
        var listN = new List<int>();
        for(int i = 0, x = 0; x < 50; i+=13, x++) { 
            listM.Add(i);
        }
        for(int i = 0, x = 0; x < 10000; i+=7, x++) { 
            listN.Add(i);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(SortedExcept(listM, listN).Count);
    }

    public static List<T> SortedExcept<T>(List<T> m, List<T> n) {
        var result = new List<T>();
        foreach(var itm in m) {
            var index = n.BinarySearch(itm);
            if(index < 0) { 
                result.Add(itm); 
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

**EDIT** Here's the O(M + N) version as well

```
public static List<T> SortedExcept2<T>(List<T> m, List<T> n) where T : IComparable<T> {
    var result = new List<T>();
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    if(n.Count == 0) {
        result.AddRange(m);
        return result;
    }
    while(i < m.Count) {
        if(m[i].CompareTo(n[j]) < 0) {
            result.Add(m[i]);
            i++;
        } else if(m[i].CompareTo(n[j]) > 0) {
            j++;
        } else {
            i++;
        }
        if(j >= n.Count) {
            for(; i < m.Count; i++) { 
                result.Add(m[i]); 
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

In a quick & dirty benchmark  http://ideone.com/Y2oEQD  M + N is always faster even when N is 10million. BinarySearch suffers penalties because it's accessing array memory in a non-linear fashion; this causes cache misses which slows down the algorithm, so the larger N gets the more memory access penalties with BinarySearch.

Comment: Actually, I am afraid I cannot escape a O(n) complexity - it corresponds to the size of the biggest list and I have to copy it... Another solution would be to keep track of the indexes I want to delete (at most m) and work with them all along the other methods.

Answer (score 2):

If both lists are sorted, then you can implement your own solution easily:

listA except listB algorithm then works as follows:

```
1. Start from the beginning of both lists
2. If listA element is smaller than the listB element,
   then include the listA element in the output and advance listA
3. If listB element is smaller than the listA element, advance listB
4. If listA and listB elements are equal,
   advance both lists and do not push the element to the output
```

Repeat until listA is exhausted. Take special care that listB might be exhausted before listA.

Comment: I am sorry, my question was not clear. I am looking for a complexity of O(m*ln(n)). It seems to me that your method runs in O(m+n).

Comment: O(m+n) will run faster than O(m*ln(n)).

Comment: It depends. Not under the condition ln(n) < 1 + n/m, which becomes true as n gets really big (or m small)

Comment: Could be. You can binary-search the shorter list and then take a measurement of both methods. Also, there is one powerful idea that often helps - convert the shorter list to plain array and use sequential search. For loops are tremendously fast.